# How do I start the inductive step?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $x$ be any real number greater than -1. Prove that $(1 + x)^n\;\ge\;1+nx$ for every $n\ge0$ by induction.

The basis step is easy. I am struggling with starting the inductive step. Can you give me tip on how to start proving that $(1 + x)^{k+1}\;\ge\;1+(k+1)x$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $(1 + x)^{k + 1} = (1 + x)^k(1 + x)$.  Now use the induction hypothesis that $(1 + x)^k \geq 1 + kx$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply:

$\begin{align}
  (1 + x)^k &\ge 1 + k x \\
  (1 + x)^{k + 1} &\ge (1 + x) \cdot (1 + k x) \\
                  &\vdots
\end{align}$

Comment: I got to $(1+x)^{k+1} \ge 1+(k+1)x+kx^2$. I can't see how can I continue from there. How do I deal with the $kx^2$ ?

Comment: Notice that since $k$ is a non-negative integer, $kx^2 \geq 0$.  Thus, $$(1 + x)^{k + 1} \geq 1 + (k + 1)x + kx^2 \geq 1 + (k + 1)x$$ which is what you needed to prove.